# Invalidate an old session in Flask

Tags: python, flask

How do I create a new clean session and invalidate the current one in Flask?

Do I use `make_null_session()` or `open_session()`?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I do this by calling [`session.clear()`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#dict.clear).

EDIT:

After reading your comment in another answer, I see that you're trying to prevent a replay attack that might be made using a cookie that was issued in the past. I solved that problem as much as possible* with this approach:

- Override SecureCookieSessionInterface.save_session(), copying the code from the overridden version rather than calling it.
- When the overridden version of `save_session()` calls `save_cookie()`, make it pass a `session_expires` argument 30 minutes in the future. This causes cookies more than 30 minutes old to be considered invalid.
- Make the overridden version of `save_session()` update a session variable every so often, to make sure the cookie and its `session_expires` time get rewritten regularly. (I name this session variable '_refresh' and store the current time in it, then rewrite it only if more than a few seconds have passed since the last-stored time. This optimization avoids rewriting the cookie on every HTTP request.)

Duplicating Flask code in the custom `save_session()` makes this approach a bit ugly and brittle, but it is necessary in order to change the arguments passed to `save_cookie()`. It would be nice if Flask made this easier, or at least implemented its own safeguard against replay attacks.

*WARNING: This approach by itself will not stop replay attacks that might happen during a session cookie's valid lifetime. This fundamental problem with cookie-based sessions is discussed in [RFC 6896](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6896#section-7.2) and [A Secure Cookie Protocol by Liu, Kovacs, Huang, Gouda](http://www.cse.msu.edu/%7Ealexliu/publications/Cookie/cookie.pdf).

Comment: This doesn't seem to invalidate the current session. Do you know if that is possible to do?

Comment: Flask's built-in sessions are cookie-based with hashes and timestamps for validation, so there's no such thing as invalidating them in the way that you would with a key-based database-storage-backed session. You could override `SecureCookieSessionInterface.save_session()` to call `save_cookie()` with a `session_expires` argument in the past, but why bother? Calling `session.clear()` removes all data from the session, leaving it empty. Isn't that good enough?

Comment: Oh, I see what you're after. I just edited my answer with an approach that should help you.

Comment: If `session_expires` set to 30 minutes, users will be logged out from their sessions after 30 minutes of inactivity.

Answer (score 12):

If you have security concerns (and everyone should have) There is the answer:

**This is not REALLY possible**

Flask uses cookie-based sessions. When you edit or delete session, you send a REQUEST to CLIENT to remove the cookie, normal clients (browsers) will do. But if session hijacked by an attacker, the attacker's session remains valid.

Comment: I am not certain what you mean by saying that normal clients (browsers) would remove the cookie on logout. I don't see that happening in Chrome or FF. Now when I say logout, I would expect the framework, Flask in our case, to invalidate the session in the backend, irrespective of what the client prefers to do with the cookie. I would agree that Flask-Login is apparently handling sessions with cookies or more precisely, the logout_user() from Flask-Login is may be not doing what it sounds to be doing.

Answer (score 11):

You can add an [`after_request`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Flask.after_request) callback to remove the session cookie if a particular flag is set:

```
@app.after_request
def remove_if_invalid(response):
    if "__invalidate__" in session:
        response.delete_cookie(app.session_cookie_name)
    return response
```

Then you simply set that session key whenever you want to invalidate the session:

```
@app.route("/logout")
def logout():
    session["__invalidate__"] = True
    return redirect(url_for("index"))
```

See also: http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/wrappers/#werkzeug.wrappers.BaseResponse.delete_cookie

Comment: But will this invalidate the current session? I want to make it so that the user tries to use the old session cookie, it will not work. Is this possible?

Comment: @Tyilo - Are you worried about replay attacks?

Comment: @Tyilo - You'll want to take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/12472337/135978 for a good starting point there.

Answer (score 2):

If you use default flask sessions and set the app.permanent_session_lifetime, then the session will not work if a user tries to replay the same session as long as the session has expired.If you look at the source code for open_session, there is line:

```
max_age = total_seconds(app.permanent_session_lifetime)
try:            
    data = s.loads(val, max_age=max_age)
    return self.session_class(data)
    except BadSignature:
        return self.session_class()
```