# Flask signed API requests

Tags: python, flask

I'm looking for a way that I can protect my REST API uses Flask from replay attacks. Are there any Python libraries for authentication that is suitable for use with REST API and provides replay attack protection?

Here is an example endpoint that requires authentication:

```py
@app.route('/', methods=["POST"])
@auth_required
def trade():
    ticker = request.json["ticker"]
    price = request.json["price"]
    amount = request.json["amount"]
    return trade(ticker, price, amount, auth())
```

Comment: https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-KVSession/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30848665/flask-how-to-prevent-replay-attacks