# How to delete Flask HTTP Sessions from the Database on session.clear()

Tags: python, flask

I implemented a server side Session in Flask with SQLAlchemy based on this [snippit](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/110/):

```
class SqlAlchemySession(CallbackDict, SessionMixing):
    ...

class SqlAlchemySessionInterface(SessionInterface):
    def __init__(self, db):
        self.db = db

    def open_session(self, app, request):
        ...

    def save_session(self, app, session, response):
        ...
```

Everything works as expected. When the user logs in, a session is stored in the database, and the session id is placed in a cookie and returned to the user. When the user logs out, `session.clear()` is called, and the cookie is removed from the user.

However, the session is not deleted from the database. I was hoping that I could implement this logic in my `SqlAlchemySessionInterface` class, as opposed to defining a function and calling this instead of `session.clear()`.

Likewise, in the [sessions.py](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/master/flask/sessions.py) code, there isn't any reference to `clear`, and the only time a cookie is deleted is [if the session was modified](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/master/flask/sessions.py).

The [API documentation for sessions](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/api/#sessions) also doesn't indicate how the `clear` method works.

Would anyone know of a way of accomplishing this, other than replacing all my calls to `session.clear()` with:

```
def clear_session():
    sid = session.get('sid')
    if sid:
        db.session.query(DBSession).filter_by(sid=sid).delete()
        db.session.commit()
    session.clear()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13735024/invalidate-an-old-session-in-flask

Comment: @IvanCai This question is about deleting the database record that identifies a session, not about clearing the cookie.

Comment: @MatthewMoisen Did you ever found a solution? In my database, also sessions pile up.

Comment: I use server-side sessions in conjunction with Flask-Login. In Flask-Login you are supposed to call `flask_login.logout_user()`, when someone hits the endpoint to logout. I found that I also need to call `session.clear()` to get this session also removed from the DB. Main problem is that now I get a lot of sessions in my DB for anonymous users. Those sessions never get cleared as there is no job to remove expired sessions :-(

Answer (score -1):

If you want to remove duplication, you can define a function called `logout_user`

In that function, you can remove the session record from your database as well as `session.clear()`.

Call this function when `\logout` or wherever suitable.