# Redact passwords in jetty request logs

Tags: logging, jetty, classpath

I'm working on an application that sends some sensitive information as plain text via the URL query string. My goal is to customize my jetty requestlog so that any sensitive information is redacted or removed before being logged.

So far I've tried making a custom filter which did remove sensitive information from the query string but when I kept the native jetty logging enabled I was getting double logs (one with password and one without) and when I disabled the native logging I wasn't getting invalid traffic (requests that come to the correct service but have some other issue with the query string).

My question is, is there a way to either keep using my filter and not have jetty log a duplicate entry with the same information or is there a different method to clean up passwords (How can I implement a different logger, modify jetty requestlog jar?). I'm almost brand new to the world of development so I have no idea what's possible.

filter for reference

```
@Component
@Order(1)
public class RequestLogFilter implements Filter {

    private final static Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(RequestLogFilter.class);

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {

    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
        String uriPath = req.getRequestURI();
        String uri = req.getQueryString();

        uri = uri != null ? uri.replaceAll("password.+?&", "password=redacted&") : "";

        String method = req.getMethod();
        String ip = req.getRemoteAddr();
        String protocol = req.getProtocol();

        String logString = ip + " - - " + '"' + method + " " + uriPath + "?" + uri + " " + protocol + '"';
        log.info(logString);


        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);

    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        log.warn("Destructing RequestLogFilter :{}");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Caution

Putting the password in the URL query string is a bad idea.

When that is sent via HTTP (doesn't matter the version, HTTP/1.0, HTTP/1.1, HTTP/2, and HTTP/3 all have the same behavior here)
the path + query (of your URL/URI) is sent in the HTTP request-line.

So that means the URL/URI of say `https://example.com:8080/api/user?id=bob&password=axolotl` will send
something like this (HTTP/1.1 example)

```
GET /api/user?id=bob&password=axolotl HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com:8080
Connection: close
```

That request-line is logged as-is in many places, but the headers are not.
That request-line can also show up as logging during the parsing steps, or for reporting errors.

The entire request-line is also present in the Servlet Spec as part of `RequestDispatcher`
based calls in the `HttpServletRequest.getAttributes()`, which can be logged too.

That query string is also used by the browser for sending `Referer` headers to other resources.

That query string is now part of your HTTP Client (browser, and various http libraries,
including rest libs, and even phone software) will cache that request and query string.
Browser history will show that query string too.

The query string is also subject to extra behaviors on the Servlet Spec.

If you use `HttpServletRequest.getParameter("password")`, that forces the entire request to
be read to find a "parameter" in both the query string and request body content (if the
request body content happens to be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data` then
that parameter can also get it's value from the request body content.

If you (or any 3rd party library) uses the Servlet Spec include/exclude features, then
the query string MUST be merged from the original request to the sub-requests to satisfy
the include/exclude behaviors.

Some other suggestions for not using the query section for passwords.

- [Is an HTTPS query string secure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323200/is-an-https-query-string-secure)
- [How to safely include password in query string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14409930/how-to-safely-include-password-in-query-string)
- [Passing username and password in HTTP GET query parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36820000/passing-username-and-password-in-http-get-query-parameters)
- https://blog.httpwatch.com/2009/02/20/how-secure-are-query-strings-over-https/
- [Are secret URLs truly secure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4833314/are-secret-urls-truly-secure)
- [Bad idea to pass username and password in the URL when using SSL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4884863/bad-idea-to-pass-username-and-password-in-the-url-when-using-ssl)
- [Are querystring parameters secure in HTTPS (HTTP + SSL)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2629222/are-querystring-parameters-secure-in-https-http-ssl)

### Easiest and Safest Solution

If you can switch from `GET` and query string to `POST` and use either
`application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data` request body content
you will see many benefits, including the lack of logging everywhere in jetty
for request body content.

### Logging Specific Solution (A Terrible Hack)

If you still want to handle this at the logging side you basically have to do the following.

Capture all logging output events, from all logging libraries (java.util.logging, log4j, slf4j, jakarta-commons-logging, juli logging, etc)
route them to a single logging implementation (you can do this with slf4j easily enough, just choose the right combination of slf4j jars)
Then have a custom logging implementation that looks at ALL logging messages for the keyword you need to redact
and change the logging message accordingly before it's appended to the output (be it console, or log file, etc)

log4j has some support for modifying the logging message starting in 1.2.15+

See: [LOG4J: Modify logged message using custom appender](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7756308/log4j-modify-logged-message-using-custom-appender)

Comment: Thank you, I do also plan on getting passwords out of the query string eventually but that will come in a bit.

I'm not too familiar with logging so I just wanted to make confirm something. If I'm running my application in a standalone jetty server that gets a war file will a custom appender stop jetty's native logs or will I need to turn them off manually? (I'll try this out today so I can probably figure this out by then).

Comment: if you have `slf4j-api-<ver>.jar` present in the classloader, Jetty 9 will use it. (Jetty 10+ will only use slf4j-api)  You can also configure Jetty 9 to use java.util.logging.  In Jetty 9, requestlog is highly custom. In Jetty 10, RequestLog is super flexible and can use slf4j-api for output routing/filtering.

Comment: If you have un-redacted logs that you want to send to a third party, you can use Sublime Text to retrospectively redact them - see  https://codingrob.medium.com/how-to-redact-text-from-hundreds-of-text-files-in-less-than-60-seconds-511b4b91c2d8